# Parse query to not return object that have a nil pointer?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am querying PFObject A. PFObject A can have a pointer to PFObject B.

I want to get "A" objects but I don't want to get those that have no pointer to B.

How can I do that?

EDIT:
To clarify better my question I am editing it:

PFObject A has a pointer to B.

In a query I query for A objects, but I want the query to return any A objects that don't have a valid pointer to B.

So, "don't return A if B pointer in A is not found"...

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question.  Are you asking how to retrieve a specific object from Parse?  Are you trying to query for specific data within an object?

Comment: Use `whereKeyExists` http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKeyExists:

Answer (score 0):

If you stored your PFObjectB's `objectId`, then perhaps something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectBID <> %@", nil];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyObjectClassName" predicate:predicate];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *anObject in objects)
    {
        NSLog(@"getNoneNilObjects error: %@ objects: %@", error, anObject);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for query modifiers such as `whereKeyExists` or `whereKeyDoesNotExist`.

If you are concerned that the key does exist (pointer to B) however B has actually been deleted, then you can use `whereKeyExists` then just run a query of B with objectId. Loop through A objects and put their Ids in a new array. Then do something like: `[bQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:objectIdArray];`. Whatever B objects returned would confirm that those A objects with pointers are pointing to valid B objects.